Подскажите инструмент для аннотирования (разметки) текста в котором текст можно отредактировать при необходимости в процессе разметки
Я попробовал большое количество инструментов с открытым исходным кодом. И ни в одном из них нет возможности поправить текст в процессе разметки.
Общая задача такая:

Исходный текст это автоматическая транскрипция с аудио
Разметчик (аннотатор) выделяет в тексте ключевые слова, определяет эмоциональный окрас употребления этих слов, добавляет каждому выделенному слову ключевое слово.
Исправляет ошибки автоматической транскрибации

В таких иснтрументах как:

Label Studio
Diffgram
Classifai
И других менее известных

Ни в одном из этих инструментов напрочь нет возможности поправить текст в процессе разметки. Ко всему остальному "претензий" нет)
Существует ли инструмент, который позволяет редактировать текст в процессе разметки? И если нет то как в моем случае правильно выполнять разметку с точки зрения процесса?

INCEpTION — это инструмент для аннотирования, который позволяет редактировать текст во время аннотации. Попробуйте этот инструмент для исправления ошибок транскрипции и добавления аннотаций.
Brat - это инструмент с открытым исходным кодом, который позволяет размечать текст и при необходимости редактировать его. Вроде бы он обладает неплохими возможностями для разметки текста.
LightTag - это еще один пример инструмента для аннотирования и редактирования текста
tagtog - редактор текстовых аннотаций
Яшихина Е.В. (науч. рук. Вайгандт Н.Ю.) ОБЗОР ИНСТРУМЕНТОВ ДЛЯ РАЗМЕТКИ ТЕКСТОВЫХ ДАННЫХ

Как идея можно предложить доработки инструментов, те, что open source (Label Studio, Doccano) Вы можете форкнуть проект на GitHub и добавить функциональность редактирования текста.


Попробуйте использовать инструмент doccano.
Чуть поискал про него информацию, и говорят что он может справиться с вашей задачей.
Самолично я не проверял но надеюсь что вам поможет)

К сожалению там тоже нет возможности редактировать текст в процессе разметки(

жаль что не получилось

Смотрели на Prodigy AI?
Во время разметки там можно редактировать текст

Пробовал в их демо версии но не увидел возможности редактирования. По описанию тоже вроде не упоминается такая функция
